# include() is giving me error

Tags: php

my code for the page id like this

**PAGE NAME** : test.php

**content** :

```
ob_start();
include("test.php");
$GeneratedHTML = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $GeneratedHTML;
```

which give me error like this

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40961 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 2**

can anyone tell me why it is giving me error when I am including same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop.

test.php is including test.php which is including test.php which is...

Rename either the file you are including, or the name of the file this code is in.

Comment: alternatively, change it to "include_once" ;P